# ¿Como obtener el valor de un CheckBox Seleccionado en una vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

espero me puedan apoyar! Estoy tratando de obtener el valor de un checkbox creado en mi vista, pero a la hora de enviar el formulario, me llega el valor en falso aun seleccionando el checkBox.

Lo que hice es crear propiedades en mi modelo para almacenar el valor

```
 public class EmpleadoModel
    {
        public int IdEmpleado { get; set; }
        public string NoEmpleado { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Laptop")]
        public bool FacilityLaptop { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Teléfono")]
        public bool FacilityTelefono { get; set; }
}
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
 <div class="row mb-2">
            <label class="form-label">Selecciona los facilities del empleado</label>
            <div class="col">
                
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="FacilityLaptop" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="FacilityLaptop"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="FacilityTelefono" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="FacilityTelefono"></label>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Mi controlador esta de esta manera:

```
 public async Task Crear(EmpleadoModel empleado)
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        empleado.NoEmpleado = guid.ToString();

        using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var idEmpleado = await connection.QuerySingleAsync<int>("WebCHInsertarEmpleado", new
        {
            empleado.NoEmpleado,
            empleado.FacilityLaptop,
            empleado.FacilityTelefono
        }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        empleado.IdEmpleado = idEmpleado;
    }
```

Este es mi servicio:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Crear(EmpleadoModel empleado)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(empleado);
        }

        empleado.IdUsuario = servicioUsuario.ObtenerIdUsuario();
        await repositorioEmpleado.Crear(empleado);

        if(empleado.IdEmpleado == 0 && empleado.NoEmpleado == "")
        {
            TempData["mensajeError"] = "Hubó un error al crear el empleado, favor de ponerse en contanto con el área de sistemas.";
        }

        TempData["mensaje"] = "Se creó de manera correcta el empleado con el NoEmpleado: " + empleado.NoEmpleado;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Como comenté al principio, cuando le doy enviar, los valores de los check me los manda en falso, aún si seleccione la casilla. Espero me puedan apoyar en ver mi error.

Comment: Y como envías esos datos al controlador?

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta, se me olvido insertar el servicio para el POST

Comment: por qué no pones un punto de interrupción y te fijas en el `modelState` sí te da el valor que pusiste

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero sigue trayendome falso aun cuando selecciono el checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al colocar un `value` incorrecto se tiene es comportamiento anómalo. Es decir debes cambiar esto:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="FacilityLaptop" value="">
```

Por esto:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="FacilityLaptop">
```

*(sin el `value=""`)*

Tambien debería funcionar con valores `true/false`

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="FacilityLaptop" value="true">
```

En este último caso el checkbox funciona y se enviaran los valores correctamente. Pero al colocar el value como true o false no se mostrarán como tales, porque un checkbox no guarda los valores en el atributo value si no que lo hace en el atributo `checked` (ahí lo anómalo del asunto)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Yussef, funciono super bien!!