# Problema con input checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, input, checkbox

Tengo una tabla en una vista de `asp.net mvc` y en esta vista tengo una tabla para mostrar todos los registros de usuarios que tengo en mi base de datos.

Recientemente le agregue una nueva columna para ponerle un `input` de tipo `checkbox` para poder seleccionarlos y ver si estan `checked` o no. Pero cuando quiero seleccionar otro, no me deja y al picarle a uno de abajo, se mueve nada más el de hasta arriba.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-off-danger custom-switch-on-success" bis_skin_checked="1">
 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch3" name="Habilitado" value="@item.AgenteId" @(item.Activo ? "checked" : "")>
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch3"></label>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando una clase de adminTLE

Aquí esta el código completo de la vista que tengo.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">
                    Agente
                    @*@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Agregar", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info float-right" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("Agregar", "<i class=\"fas fa-plus\"></i>"))*@
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AgentesCreate"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Habilitado</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServicioNivel.Descripcion)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Correo)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefonoOficina)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefonoMovil)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rol)</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-off-danger custom-switch-on-success" bis_skin_checked="1">
 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch3" name="Habilitado" value="@item.AgenteId" @(item.Activo ? "checked" : "")>
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch3"></label>
</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.ServicioNivel.Descripcion
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Nombre
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Correo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.TelefonoOficina
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.TelefonoMovil
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Rol
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button"
                                            class="btn btn-info"
                                            data-toggle="modal"
                                            data-target="#AgentesEdit"
                                            data-agenteid="@item.AgenteId"
                                            data-nombre="@item.Nombre"
                                            data-correo="@item.Correo"
                                            data-servicionivelid="@item.ServicioNivel.ServicioNivelId"
                                            data-telefonooficina="@item.TelefonoOficina"
                                            data-telefonomovil="@item.TelefonoMovil"
                                            data-rol="@item.Rol">
                                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="AgentesPorCategorias(@item.AgenteId);"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="AgentesPorSucursales(@item.AgenteId);"><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt"></i></button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="jsEliminar2(@item.AgenteId);"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Habilitado</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServicioNivel.Descripcion)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Correo)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefonoOficina)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefonoMovil)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rol)</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No entendí el comportamiento anómalo que describes, puedes explicarlo de otra forma? Además ojo con el `value` del checkbox no puede ser cualquier cosa, mira esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/584514/301324

Comment: Te puse una imagen para que pudieras entenderme un poco mejor. Lo que pasa es que cuando quiero seleccionar el checkbox que esta en rojo, no me deja y cuando lo hago es como si selecciono al primero, nada más ese se mueve

Comment: Ahora entiendo.....coloca el código completo de la vista

Comment: Listo, ya lo edite

Comment: Ahora tengo más dudas: El código del checkbox no es el mismo que el primer código que has puesto, porque? Luego, cuando presionas el checkbox que debería pasar, se guarda automáticamente o hay un botón submit que manda a guardar todo?

Comment: Mala mía, es que estaba probando con otras cosas pero el primero es el que estoy usando. Cuando presiono el checkbox se manda a un controlador con el value del agente y el valor del checked. Esos botones que están ahí, son aparte.

Comment: Es que tengo la sospecha de lo que puede ser, pero para comprobarlo necesito ver el código exacto

Comment: Ya lo edite exactamente como lo tengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas repitiendo la `ID` tanto el mismo atributo como en el atributo `for`

La técnica utilizada para dar estilo a los `checkbox` es hacer invisibles estos y dar estilo al `label`, cuando haces click en dicho label se activa/desactiva el checkbox que esta enlazado a él mediante el atributo `for`. Y si tienes todos con el mismo `id` el navegador tomará uno solo, generalmente el primero.

Puedes ir generando un `id` mediante un contador

```
@{
    int cont = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    cont++;
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-off-danger custom-switch-on-success" bis_skin_checked="1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch_@cont" name="Habilitado" value="@item.AgenteId" @(item.Activo ? "checked" : "")>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch_@cont"></label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Eso era, gracias.